MurgaLua 0.7.5 and use of fltk function saveAsPng()
i am stuck with a personal code murgaLua 0.7.5 (OS Linux Lubuntu LTS, but it should work in Windows) that captures in a fltk graphic window (created by the code) a diagram image and writes it in png format. Unfortunately, this MurgaLua-specific PNG image writing function, saveAsPng(), seems slower than the calculation of the histogram table, and as I have several diagrams to write, either I have a "core dumped" message, or only the last diagram is saved, or, and this is the current solution, a fltk "modal window" is displayed to delay the operations, and I get the different images on disk. The problem is the volume: I want to write an automatic report with potentially more than 500 diagrams! The test data file is an OpenData file of more than 450 MB, downloadable here:
https://open-data-assurance-maladie.ameli.fr/medicaments/download_file2.php?file=Open_MEDIC_Base_Complete/OPEN_MEDIC_2023.zip
And the complete murgaLua code is here
https://github.com/mterras01/murgaLua/blob/main/statsoncsv_next2.lua
Following function is fully working
function read_Image()
   pwindow:make_current()
   Fl:check()
   Fl:flush()
   imageString = fltk.fl_read_image(0, 0, width_pwindow, height_pwindow)
   Fl:check()
   Fl:flush()
   image2 = fltk:Fl_RGB_Image(imageString, width_pwindow, height_pwindow, 3, 0)
   Fl:check()
   Fl:flush()
   fileName = title .. ".png"
   image2:saveAsPng(fileName)
end

It is called from a for-loop (successive images).
(I know murgaLua is an old language (i'm 59 old) written by John de Murga).
i successfully can save all my charts with
  Fl:check()
  pwindow:show()
  pwindow:redraw()
  Fl:flush()
  pwindow:set_modal()
  if fltk:fl_choice("Save Charts or not ?", "No", "Yes", nil) == 1 then
     read_Image()
  end
  pwindow:set_non_modal()

but have to click each time to save. Not the good way to build a 500 images report.

In the meantime, i tried : Lua coroutine (threads-like), then fltk Fl-timer : both give "core dumped" error while reading/saving first chart.

important : fltk version in murgaLua 0.7.5 is 1.1.10.

Other important info : solution given in https://onexception.dev/news/1385946/saving-fltk-diagrams-as-png-in-murgalua is IA bullshit.

If you really depend on such an old version of murgaLua and thus on FLTK 1.1.10 there's probably not much to help you. Since FLTK 1.3.x and even more in FLTK 1.4.0 (to be released soon) you can draw to offline images and then you could write the offline image data to a PNG file. This should work in a loop w/o drawing to the display at all, although you should provide a way to interrupt the process (this can be done by a button setting a flag in its callback).

... although just I noticed that basic "offline drawing" features already exist in 1.1.x, see documentation at https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.1/drawing.html#offscreen . I'm not sure though how to retrieve the pixel data of the offscreen area which can be done easily in 1.4. The entire offscreen drawing functionality has been improved very much in 1.3 and even more in 1.4.0.

Thanks for these advices Albrecht Schlosser : i'll give it a try. Too bad murgaLua has not much  future, it was a real Lua gem embedding some fltk within a few hundred of kb (Linux-macos-windows), and so much more, and no dependencies...

So i found answer to my question. Again, thanks to Albrecht Schlosser (danke sehr!), for its suggestion. It seems that (one) solution was to open a countdown-autoclosing-fltk-modal-window that makes "synchro" graphic (draw charts) & computing tasks (read-convert and save images-as-a-file for each charts). This fully works with Linux OS, but there is a 45-sec-lag with Windows (in  today version, work in progress, if interested, see my github)... It's more easy to write this script with python, but murgaLua is such a GEM.Please,please developpers, consider about updating this GEM !
